# how to use Fourier transform to predict future trend by fitting the dominant frequency

Tags: matlab, fft, data-fitting

Here I have several depth profiles at the same location. This profiles were measured in a time series but not in evenly time interval. I decomposed those profiles by FFT and found the dominant frequency. Then I found the amplitudes of the dominant frequencies in each profile fit exponential regression. So how can I use this point to predict future development of the profiles. It's like you give a time then you get a profile.

Here my idea is to fit amplitude with the time. But I can only fit the real part of the complex not the imaginary part. As long as I change the value of the imagina part then the inverse FFT, the profiles would disappear. And I don't know why...

[image]

Here is part of the program

```
%fitting%forecast
pp1=polyfit(xx,YY1,1);
%pp2=polyfit(xx,YY2,1);
xx=log([5000 10000 20000 30000 50000 100000 500000]);
p1=pp1(1)*xx+pp1(2);
%p2=(pp2(1)*xx+pp2(2))*1i;
p=p1;%+p2;
%kk2=imag(Y1);
kk1=real(Y1);
%kk2(:,6)=kk2(:,5);
%kk2(:,7)=kk2(:,5);
kk1(:,6)=kk1(:,5);
kk1(:,7)=kk1(:,5);
kk1(5,:)=p;
kk1(91,:)=p;
kk=kk1;%+kk2*1i;
%as long as I fit the imaginary part the profile becomes strange 
k=ifft(kk);
plot(a1)
hold on
plot(k,'*')
```